# How to detect a UWP (universal windows platform) app is running as a published application or testing application at run-time?

Tags: windows, store, publish, universal, uap

I would like to make part my UWP application logic a bit different when the application run as a published store app instead of a engineering edition.
So the question is how can I detect at the run-time whether a UWP application is running as a published store app?
Thanks for any suggestions.